# How to stop 'html_entity_decode' reducing font size in smaller screens?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, font-size, htmldecode

I am retrieving body text from the database in phpmyadmin. To remove the html entities I have written the following code:

```
<h4><?php echo html_entity_decode($post['body']); ?></h4>
```

However by adding the 'html_entity_decode', this reduces the font size significantly in smaller screens but goes back to normal when the decode is removed. How can I fix this?

p.s - I have tried overriding the h4 in css with an !important tag as well for smaller screens but nothing works. Thanks.

Comment: You should post this as a CSS issue where you show the generated HTML and your CSS that you say doesn't work. All `html_entity_decode()` does is converting html entities back to the original html again. Where does the string originally come from?

Comment: PHP functions do not alter styles AFAIK. Your style must be coming from elsewhere. You can usually inspect the `<h4>` and check the computed section, might give you a hint where it is coming from

Comment: The string comes from a form input value @MagnusEriksson. Sure, noted for next time

Comment: I have now inspected the elements and the CSS style over riding all my other styles was nowhere to be seen which is baffling! So I just added that over riding CSS back into the stylesheet and now it works! Thanks @MehrdadDastgir